# How to show 1k,1M & 1B in numbers using Intl api in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to show 1k,1M and 1B in numbers using Intl api in javascript?

`let num = 1000;`

`if(num == 1000){`

`num = num + "k";`

`}`

expected input :

1000

expected output :

1K

Above logic i have used but i need javascript inbuilt feature to achieve this logic

Comment: Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here I am Using [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) to format numbers.

```js
let formatter = Intl.NumberFormat('en', { notation: 'compact' });

let thousand = formatter.format(1000);
let million = formatter.format(1000000);
let billion = formatter.format(1000000000);
let trillion = formatter.format(1000000000000);

console.log(thousand); //1K
console.log(million); //1M
console.log(billion); //1B
console.log(trillion); //1T
```